# Background image from API

Tags: html, angular, background-image, spotify

I am using the Spotify API in my Angular application and I was wondering if you can set background image from an object from the API? 
I tried something like this

```
<div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
   <div style="background-image: url("artist.images[2].url")">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A tip, it is fine to create an Answer yourself and then to accept that answer. It may even be better than what you did, because people expect *Answers* to contain the answer, and not the *Question itself* to contain the answer.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer working in Angular 5:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'url('+artist.images[2].url+')'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed something here, Angular needs double curly braces to render scope variables in the template (when you won't use it in the directive, such as ngIf, etc.):

```
<div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
   <div style="background-image: url("{{ artist.images[2].url }}")">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, I forgot about that, but the syntax still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
<div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
    <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+artist.images[2].url+')'}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that before I post the question here, it didn't work because I didn't use the new Angular syntax [ngStyle] (I use Angular 5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
   <img [src]="url">
</div>
```

Where `url` is your image url.

Comment: This works if my aim is to just add the image, not set it as background.

Answer (score 0):

beside the double curly braces enguerranws mentioned ...

according to the [spotify docs](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/console/get-several-artists/) it should state:

```
<div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
  <div style="background-image: url("{{ data.artists[0].images[0].url }}")">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use [ngStyle] for Angular to use the url from API.